# Как подсчитать MD5 хеш и SHA1 хеш для неупорядоченного конечного множества

Tags: java, хеширование, hashset

Доброго времени суток.

**Задача:** реализовать метод hashMd5() для класса представляющей собой НЕ УПОРЯДОЧЕННОЕ конечное множество таким образом, чтобы он возвращал MD5 хеш.
Метод hashMd5() должен выполнять то же контракт по отношению к методу equals(), что и hashcode().

**В чем сложность:** когда для некоторого Java объекта необходимо посчитать MD5 хеш, то его сперва преобразуют в массив байт с помощью ObjectOutputStream. Потом этот массив байт скармливают алгоритму вычисляющему MD5 хеш. Однако такой подход негодится при реализации hashode() для НЕ УПОРЯДОЧЕННЫХ множеств, т.к. (например) для двух равных множеств A={1,2,3} и B={1,3,2} будут получены разные массивы байт и следовательно рассчитаны разные MD5 хеши.

**Вопрос:** собственно, как можно решить поставленную задачу?

Comment: Что-то задача в принципе непонятна, hashCode() возвращает int который 4 байта, и MD5 в него физически никак не поместится... Или вы берёте какие-то отдельные байты из полученного MD5?

Comment: Спасибо за замечание, исправил. В действительности нужно реализовать метод, который выполняет контракт hashcode().

Comment: Очевидно придётся сначала их упорядочить. Либо использовать какую-нибудь коммутативную операцию. Например банально сложить все значения

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Создаем какую-нибудь коллекцию поддерживающую упорядоченный набор элементов(например, ArrayList).
2. Наполняем её элементами из нашей неизменяемой коллекции.
3. Сортируем элементы.
4. Скармливаем отсортированную коллекцию объекту ObjectOutputStream.
5. Из объекта ObjectOutputStream получаем массив байт.
6. Скармливаем массив байт объекту MessageDigest и получаем на выходе нужный хеш.

Comment: Это сработает, если у вас тип значений поддерживает сравнение на больше-меньше. А если нет?
В общем случае нужно приводить элементы к чему-нибудь, что можно сравнивать. Например, на втором этапе вашего алгоритма наполнять не самими элементами, а их хэшами.

Comment: Могли бы вы привести пример типа значений, для которого нельзя задать линейный порядок.

Comment: Далеко не всякий тип в Java поддерживает сравнение на больше-меньше. А именно любой тип, который не реализует тип Comparable<T>. Например, java.lang.Object. Если вы попробуете отсортировать ArrayList<Object>, то получите отлуп ```    method Collections.<T#1>sort(List<T#1>) is not applicable
      (inference variable T#1 has incompatible bounds
        equality constraints: Object
        upper bounds: Comparable<? super T#1>)```
План б - потребовать в интерфейсе вашего вычислителя хэш-кода передавать компаратор, который вы будете использовать для сортировки.

Comment: Если какой-либо тип не реализует Comparable<T>, то у нас всегда есть интерфейс Comparator<T>.

Comment: И второе соображение. Хэш-код объекта не должен меняться на протяжении жизни объекта. Для этого ваше множество должно не просто быть неизменным, неизменными должны быть все объекты на всю глубину. То есть для множества строк хэш вычислить можно, а для множества StringBuilder - нет.